# Carousel height adjustment

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel

I want to display Carousel in a rectangle (height

[image]

You can check my code here:

```
<div>
                <NavBar/>
                <div className="carousel-wrapper">
                    <Carousel width={"40%"}>
                        {
                            this.state.images.map((photo, index) => (
                                <div>
                                    <img src={photo}/>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }


                    </Carousel>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As suggested by @Awais, I have added following styling for image:

```
Carousel autoPlay={true}showArrows={true} width={"70%"} showIndicators={true} infiniteLoop={true} >
                            {
                                this.state.images.map((photo, index) => (
                                    <div>
                                        <img src={photo} style={{width: "100%", height:"400px",objectFit:"cover"}}/>
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </Carousel>
```

However, now the "suggestion thumbnails" look weird.

[image]

How shall I change thu,bnail dimensions?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit that what do you mean by rectangle height? Is that mean above image cover full `width` but with same `height`?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: But as you see your image is of type square if you want to to rectangle you have to compromise on image as it will cut off ill post an example below just copy those styles on your image

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in below fiddle the image is some how crop due to `object-fit:cover` property its just like `background-size:cover`

Apply the `img` style to you image in `carousel`, if its not applies try to use `!important` to override carousel styles

```css
img{
 width: 100%;/*to stretch it to full widht*/
 height: 200px;/*you image square height*/
 object-fit:cover; /*cover you image*/
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your siggestion. It meets my requirements but now the height of "suggestions thumbnail" is also changed. I have updated my question for your reference.

Comment: Did you set carousel width to `100%`? `<Carousel width={"100%"}>`

Comment: No I have set it to 100%. But even though I set it to 100% I am facing the same problem

Comment: Can you update with latest code so that i can i see whts the issue is

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni Can you inspect that element and check whether its parent have width property or the properties given on image was overridden or not? And also is their any live link so i can check it as working example